# Do I need to free a pointer which receives a dynamically allocated object from a function?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc

I am implementing a function that reads a line in C from stdin. Here is the code:

```
char * stdin_getline(){
  unsigned buffer_size = 100;
  char *string = malloc(buffer_size);
  char *string_temp;
  char temp;
  int i=0;
  while(1) {
    scanf("%c", &temp);
    if (temp == '\n') {break;}
    if (i == buffer_size-1) {
      *(string+buffer_size) = '\0';
      string_temp = malloc(buffer_size);
      strcpy(string_temp, string);
      free(string);
      buffer_size *= 2;
      string = malloc(buffer_size);
      strcpy(string, string_temp);
      free(string_temp);
    }
    *(string+i) = temp;
    i++;
  }
  *(string+i+1) = '\0';
  return string;
}

int main() {
  char *temp_line;
  temp_line = stdin_getline();
  printf("%s\n", temp_line);
  free(temp_line); // Is this line needed?
  return 0;
}
```

Do I really need to free the temp_line pointer inside the main function?

Comment: Sure, you have allocated memory in your function with malloc(buffer_size)!

Comment: `string_temp = malloc(buffer_size);
      strcpy(string_temp, string);
      free(string);
      buffer_size *= 2;
      string = malloc(buffer_size); ...`?!?!  Look up `realloc()`.

Comment: As the function is only called once and then the program ends, the code does not need to take care of freeing the memoyr, as this is done implicitly the moment the program ends. But imagine the function would be called a million over a million times for example as part of a long runnig server process, then sooner or later all available memory would be eaten up, and then ... well ... the box goes down, hangs, whatever.

Comment: Also, `*(string+i) = temp;` is `string[i] = temp;`

Comment: @alk: That behavior is not specified in the C standard. General-purpose multi-user operating systems commonly reclaim memory upon process termination, but that should not be assumed—or taught—for special-purpose environments.

Comment: Treat your function like you would treat `malloc`. Anything that has been allocated by `malloc` (and similar functions) should be freed with `free`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, is there any advantage in using string[i] instead of *(string+i), besides making the code easier for reading?

Comment: *making the code easier for reading* That's all the reason needed.  Readability is the single most important aspect of writing code - can you read it and thereby understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call is irrelevant to the question. Everything that was allocated by `malloc` must be deallocated using `free` in order to avoid memory leaks.